# How can I show the website within the application? Flutter

Tags: flutter, web, url

i have buttons with url in my application. When I click the button, it redirects to the website, but I want it to display in my application. How can I provide this?

MY Code example :

```
Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 380.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SnakeButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Blog",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 17,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () => launch('https://nisaefendioglu.blog'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this package should help...

'https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx'

Comment: Thank you. :) @speeder